# Custom filter in Lucene

Tags: c#, lucene

I created a custom filter in my analyzer to split terms by the `"/"` character.

I want that a document containing a string like `"testDocument Test/mystring/2014"` can be found searching, for example, `"test mystring"` or `"mystring 2014"`.

I implemented the following filter:

```
public class MyDelimiterFilter : TokenFilter
{

    private readonly ITermAttribute _termAtt;
    private readonly IPositionIncrementAttribute _positionAtt;
    private readonly Queue<char[]> _terms;

    public WordDelimiterFilter(TokenStream inStream)
        : base(inStream)
    {
        _termAtt = AddAttribute<ITermAttribute>();
        _positionAtt = AddAttribute<IPositionIncrementAttribute>();
        _terms = new Queue<char[]>();
    }

    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        if (_terms.Count != 0)
        {
            var buffer = _terms.Dequeue();

            _termAtt.SetTermBuffer(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
            _positionAtt.PositionIncrement = 1;
            return true;
        }

        if (!input.IncrementToken())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_termAtt.Term.Contains("/"))
        {
            var tempArray = _termAtt.Term.Split('/');
            foreach (var item in tempArray)
            {
                _terms.Enqueue(item.ToCharArray());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _terms.Enqueue(_termAtt.Term.ToCharArray());
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I can debug this code and logic path seems correct. If I try to search I found the document with `"testDocument"` or `"Test/mystring/2014"` but zero results, for example, for `"mystring"`.

What I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part  :

```
    if (_termAtt.Term.Contains("/"))
    {
        var tempArray = _termAtt.Term.Split('/');
        foreach (var item in tempArray)
        {
            _terms.Enqueue(item.ToCharArray());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _terms.Enqueue(_termAtt.Term.ToCharArray());
    }

    return true;
```

does not contain logic for setting the `_termAtt` to it's proper value , or for incrementing the position. You will return true from incrementToken more times than you have to this way.  Can you please provide a text from the `toString` method on your query object?

EDIT: it seems the query you get back is a phrase query instead of a simple term query.
Try adding this code snippet before the final `return true;` statement

```
    var buffer = _terms.Dequeue();

    _termAtt.SetTermBuffer(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    _positionAtt.PositionIncrement = 1;
```

As a debug measure, you could also print something inside the `incrementToken` method and see how many times it is called for various inputs

Comment: Query is a simple `Body:"testDocument"`; there is an online sample or can you explain how to set properly `_termAtt` and position?

Comment: Thx! Doing as you describe it works!... I speed up code doing the same operation with less calls at `IncrementToken` method. The logic seems the same (much faster yes) where's the real difference?

Comment: The difference is that when the queue is empty , a call to increment token will return true , but `_termAtt` will contain the old value instead of a newly generated one, so you end up with duplicates as far as i can tell